# In learning F# why does it recommend specifying type in the field rather than at assignment?

Tags: types, f#

In the [Learning F# tutorial](http://www.tryfsharp.org/Learn/getting-started#data-structures) there are two record types with the same set of field labels.

**Book record**

```
type Book = 
  { Name: string;
    AuthorName: string;
    Rating: int;
    ISBN: string }
```

**VHS record**

```
type VHS =
  { Name: string;
    AuthorName: string;
    Rating: string; // Videos use a different rating system.
    ISBN: string }
```

If you then create a record using these then F# will assume the last definition is the one you want to use (VHS). So under the Duplicate Label Names heading it suggests adding a type to the Rating label name like so:

```
let theFSharpQuizBook = 
  { Name = "The F# Quiz Book";
    AuthorName = "William Flash";
    Book.Rating = 5;
    ISBN = "1234123412" }
```

I would have thought that this was clearer - having the type specified in the assignment:

```
let theFSharpQuizBook : Book = 
  { Name = "The F# Quiz Book";
    AuthorName = "William Flash";
    Rating = 5;
    ISBN = "1234123412" }
```

Is there a reason that this isn't mentioned/suggested/recommended?

Comment: You can remove the `;` from each line. Semi-colon is only required if you are writing multiple expressions on the same line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I can't say why it isn't mentioned in the tutorial, there are advantages and disadvantages to both. Personally, I use both, as well as a third variation, depending on circumstances.

The first option is great when you don't need to assign the record to a variable, but instead just want to use it to kick off a pipeline, like this:

```
{   Name = "The F# Quiz Book";
    AuthorName = "William Flash";
    Book.Rating = 5;
    ISBN = "1234123412" }
|> Some
|> Option.toList
```

(Pardon the inane example, which is a really roundabout way of turning the record into a list with that single element).

On the other hand, as you say, explicitly annotating the value of the let binding may be more readable, but it requires you to use a let binding, and to give the record a name.

Here's a third option that also sometimes come in handy:

```
let theFSharpQuizBook'' = 
  { Name = "The F# Quiz Book";
    AuthorName = "William Flash";
    Rating = 5;
    ISBN = "1234123412" } : Book
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had suspected your first example would be a reason, but very handy to have the clarifying example. I am less clear in what scenario the third example should be used - would it be possible for you to include an example or a little more explanation of that point please?

Comment: @Treffynnon Actually, I can't remember... I just recall that I've occasionally found that useful, but it's not that common.

Answer (score 6):

Your thought is definitely reasonable; adding type annotation is a common technique in F#.

In this context, we could interpret the authors' suggestion as follows:

- The list of suggestions isn't meant to be exhaustive.
- Using `Book.Rating` is more interesting when discussing record types. It demonstrates a point that you can *disambiguate different record types by using **just one** label name*.

There are some cases, using label name is more natural e.g. pattern matching:

```
let getRating { Book.Rating = r } = r
```

vs

```
let getRating ({ Rating = r }: Book) = r
```

In many cases, it's a matter of personal preference when you choose one of the two conventions for use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the example code demonstrating where this makes code more readable. I agree with you that the technique demonstrated in the tutorial is more interesting and unusual.